# making a http request within a api endpoint

Tags: python, python-requests, tornado

I'm trying to make a request within a post api endpoint. So far i've made it `Async`, however i'm wondering how the behaviour is in this case. if the `fetch` fails, i would like to output a message. However since it is `Async`n i guess that `self.finish` in the bottom will be outputted before `_upload_to_nsq()` is finished? Is the best here to make it synchronous or how can i improve the code to output messages during errors?

```
class Handler(base.BaseHandler):

    def _upload_to_nsq(self):
        request = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(
            '{}:4151/pub?topic=chamelo'.format(settings.nsqdlookup_address),
            body=self.request.body.decode(),
            method="POST")

        client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
        client.fetch(request)


    def _valiate_required_fields(self):
        missing_fields = []
        all_required_fields = ['state', 'upsert', 'schema']

        for field in all_required_fields:
            if field not in self.json_args:
                missing_fields.append(field)

        if len(missing_fields) > 0:
            raise FieldException('Require following fields: %s' % ', '.join(missing_fields))


    @tornado.web.removeslash
    def post(self):
        # Validate if required keys are present
        try:
            self._valiate_required_fields()
        except FieldException as e:
            self.set_status(400)
            self.finish({
            "code": 400,
                "message": str(e)
            })

        # Post request to nsqdlookup
        try:
            self._upload_to_nsq()
        except Error as e:
            self.set_status(400)
            self.finish({
            "code": 400,
                "message": str(e)
            })

        # Everything is good

        self.set_status(200)
        self.finish({
            "code": 200,
            "message": "Ok"
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tornado is normally single-threaded, so you should not block in request handlers. Using an asynchronous client is the correct way to implement what you want.

You will have to make your own 'post' handler asynchronous, i.e., return before it has actually finished its work and complete the incoming request when the 'post' to the back-end API that you're calling completes.

See an example in the tornado documentation here:

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#decorators

(there's an example in the tornado.web.asynchronous decorator section that shows use of an AsyncHTTPClient inside a server handler method - pretty much exactly what you need here)